# Java - making different classes print to client instead of System.out

Tags: java, class, networking, io

I'm converting a working single player game to run across a network.

It's a simple game that runs on a terminal.. it's just text in / text out with the program.

It has a few classes, most of which print to System.out or System.err

but I want to send these messages to the client instead of printing them on the server system.

How can I do this, when the socket i/o is made in the main thread of one class?

Basically how do I access this from the other classes?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(45444);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 45444.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    String outputLine;
```

Comment: Basically, you should start a new thread to handle clientSocket. And you can pass the clientSocket to other class as an argument (constructor argument or just a setter method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.setOut()` and `System.setErr()` to redirect STDOUT and STDERR to arbitrary output streams (in your case, a network I/O stream).